# What is the best approach into make a website mobile-friendly?

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, jquery

I need to make our website "mobile-friendly". The site is made in ASP.NET approx 5 years ago and the option is to add mobile-friendly feature without having to recode the whole website. The website is about the collection of cars (old and new), has search feature and so on. Nothing complex, no video or audio, etc.

Since there are multiple approaches to this solution, I summed 3 best ones (in my opinion):

1. Create a 'm' version of the website
2. Create mobile application(s) which utilize newly created web services
3. Create HTML 5 + Ajax mobile version of our webpage, and put it inside of a mobile app

Now, the 1st solution is OK, but our app (brand) will not appear on any mobile app store. So this is a bad marketing solution.

The 2nd takes the most time and we have to make an app for each platform. Also it does not solve the issue of non-smartphones users accessing our website.

The 3rd solution we can use on all mobile phones, but it still have the same issue as point 2 (non-smartphone users).

Can you suggest which approach is the best taking into account time & money involved in its implementation?

I know that combination of these points would be the best (would reach everyone), but it's also most time-consuming solution.

Answer (score 1):

If your mobile version does not need any native phone features; introducing media queries in the CSS and make the site responsive would probably the fastest and easiest solution.

Answer (score -1):

Enter the url of your website into [Google's "Mobile-Friendly Test"](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/), then use the feedback from that test to update your website.